# Converting Epoc time to IST in R

Tags: r, date, epoch, converters

I have the below information in my .csv. I'm trying to convert the epoch time to IST time but unable to do so.

The information in the .csv is attached.

I'm trying to add a column and convert the epoch time to IST.

Please suggest a better way.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**sample data**

```
created_at <- c(1549480813,1549480815,1549480818,1549480872)
```

**code**

```
as.POSIXct( created_at, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "Asia/Kolkata" )
```

**output

```
#[1] "2019-02-07 00:50:13 IST" "2019-02-07 00:50:15 IST" "2019-02-07 00:50:18 IST" "2019-02-07 00:51:12 IST"
```

Comment: Thanks for the above answer

But i need it in the same csv how can i do that

Comment: @Charan I don't understand your question. You read in the csv in R, perform operations you want, and then write back to csv.

Comment: My question is, I have a csv with above data so I need to get the convert ist time in the next row.
What you have done in the above answer is you have taken all the created_at to a new data frame and then you have used the POSIXct function, whereas it's creating a new data frame.
Which I don't want I want to update the current csv with a new column telling created_at_ist

Comment: @Charan... then do so.. read in the csv into R, add the new colum using the code I provided, and write the results back to a csv-file... You can overwrite your existing csv if desired. You know how to read/write csv in R?